# How to set up a radial Gradient node

Tags: node-editor

I'm trying to set up a gradient node where I can control the middle colour to expand or contract.
This is what I have set up so far.

[image]

Example what Im trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Is that a sphere or a plane you want it on?

Comment: Just for your information, this circular effect is achieved by using the _Spherical_ mode of the _Gradient Texture_. The _Radial_ gradient results in something looking more like a "radar scan".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should feed the Gradient Texture output to Color Ramp node's factor input, if you want to remap the texture's tones to Color Ramp's colors, but it might be easier to control with Math node since you can animate it more easily:

[image]

Comment: Hello Martynas. Its a flat circle shape.

Comment: That's also a plane in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a circle just plug the Color output form the Gradient node into the color ramp factor.(Remember to use object coordinates and set the mode to Spherical)
[image]

If it's a sphere you will have to use the Layer weight or Fresnel node.
[image]

You can experiment around the values using the Map Range node and also by changing the interpolation modes in the Color Ramps in order to get different kinds of spherical gradients.

Comment: Circle is a curve, disk is part of a plane limited by that curve.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys But be careful by mixing Blender terminology with maths/geometry terminology to not confuse beginners. A _Curve_ object in Blender is something different than a _Mesh_ object, however you can have a curve circle and a mesh circle, so saying a circle is a curve is true in maths, but might be misunderstandable in Blender  ;)

Comment: You got me there. :D Still, a circle is not filled in math and it's not filled in Blender.

Comment: A circle can be filled with a triangle fan, or an n-gon, or just left empty while you are adding it to the scene. Although by default it's not filled.